# How to make sure that slack won't send a message even if I press enter?

Tags: slack, slack-commands

Looks like most slack questions deal with sending issues. I have the opposite.

In the olden days, when I was using outlook emails, I would simply add a xxx@xxx.com in the sender's list. That way, even if I click send by mistake, the mail won't be sent because there is an invalid email. I used this because I need to type a long email and don't want to send mails by mistake before it is completed and spell-checked. Is there something like this I can do for slack also?

Current solutions:

- I can chat with myself on slack. This feature is used to keep notes, reminders etc. I can use this feature for this purpose also. Just wondering if there is a better solution.
- Slack does allow you to delete messages. So, even if I send the message before completion, I can just delete and rewrite.

Comment: I don't understand your outlook trick. `xxx@xxx.com` is a valid email address, so the email would get sent. That said, this doesn't seem like a programming question, so it's off-topic here. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by updating your preferences.

**Set your Enter key preference**
Depending on the preference that you set, pressing the
key on your desktop will either send a message or start a new line in Slack. Use the steps below to change this preference at any time.

https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/115005523006-Set-your-Enter-key-preference

**Tip:** 
If you choose **'Send the message'**, you can use to `Shift` `Enter` start a new line.
If you choose **'Start a new line'**, you can use `Command` `Enter`(Mac) or `Ctrl` `Enter`(Windows/Linux) to send the message.

Comment: Updated the preferences. Let me see how I like it.